# Identify science-fiction short story where superintelligent test subjects fight with sense-based mental programming

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Some time ago, I recall reading a short sci-fi story, set in the modern or near-future day, the central premise of which was that the government/military had tested an experimental intelligence-enhancing drug. The results were initially fruitless so the test subjects all went on their ways (I presume they were paid/volunteers). However, it transpires that the drug simply has a very long onset, and the testees begin to develop extreme intelligence some time afterwards - I believe the growth in intelligence is portrayed as exponential, and possibly without limit.

The main character is one such test subject. I believe the early part of the story involves the main character seeking to evade the government/military after they realise that the drug was in fact effective (and dangerously so). He then proceeds to seek out other test subjects, but has no luck finding them or only finds them dead.

The story culminates in his encounter with another test subject, where they realise that each of them represents an unacceptable danger to the other, and they engage in a mental battle for survival. The protagonist loses, reflecting before his mind is destroyed that perhaps the other subject had their dose of the drug administered just slightly before he did, and therefore had the edge in intelligence over him. I think it is also revealed that this opponent was the one who killed the other test subjects the main character had tried to find.

I specifically remember that the super-intelligent subjects had such fine control over their bodies/mental processes and understanding of other minds that they were able to effectively mind control people by very precise visual/auditory cues to induce them to behave in the desired way (it's explicitly not telepathy). This is the method they employ in the final battle; the protagonist goes so far as to create a sort of virtual mind inside his own through which he filters all his sensory input, to protect his mind proper from the other's attacks. It's very reminiscent of the concept of Godelian Shock Input from David Langford's BLIT stories, but I don't think it's associated with Langford or his works.

I read this online a few years ago (unfortunately I cannot be more precise than that) so I'm not sure if it's originally from an anthology or similar or published online directly. I remember on the forum where I saw the link, the poster described it as an example of "somatic programmers" fighting, though I believe that terminology was not used anywhere in the story.

Comment: Hey Carcer, this question is closed as a dupe but there's no acceptance (whether from a comment or by Community user dupe-closing the post). Could you confirm the dupe is the right one? There might have been a deleted comment, but I wouldn't be able to see it. Cheers!

Comment: @Jenayah yes, I think the comments got deleted. It is definitely a duplicate and the answer in the linked question was the one I was looking for.

Comment: Great, thanks for the confirmation, keeps things cleaner! :D